# sub-group-schemes of order $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $p$ be a prime.

If $G$ is an abelian $p$-torsion group and $X\subset G$ is a **subset**  of size $p$ that is stable under $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathrm{End}(G)$, then $X$ is a **subgroup** of $G$.

My question is about the group scheme version of this.

Let $G$ be an abelian finite flat group scheme, over a Noetherian base, that is annihilated by $p$. Let $X$ be a closed **subscheme** of $G$ that is flat of rank $p$, and that is stable under $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathrm{End}(G)$. Is it true that $X$ must be a **sub-group-scheme** of $G$?

Note that it is somewhat delicate because the "size $p$" hypothesis is crucial.

Comment: Is $G$ commutative? And are you over an arbitrary (presumably Noetherian, otherwise flatness is the "wrong" condition, one wants some local finite presentation condition as well, usually) base?

Comment: I don't think this is true. How about the base $k$ alg closed of char 3, $G=\alpha_p\times\alpha_p$ with ring $A=k[x,y]/(x^3,y^3)$ and $X$ the closed subscheme defined by the ideal $(x^2,xy,y^2)$? I think $n\in\Z/p$ sends $x$ to $nx$ and $y$ to $ny$ so it's stable, but a tedious calculation (or knowledge of the rank $p$ subgroup schemes) shows that it's not a subgroup scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited the question accordingly. As far as I can see, your counter-example looks correct, can you post it as an answer?